# How to deploy Apache Cordova app from Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, apache, cordova, phonegap-build, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build an Android app in Visual Studio 2015 CTP, using the Apache Cordova plugin. I've tried downloading a sample project, and also just a very empty new Cordova project, and Debug it on either my real Android device, or ona virtual one. It does not work in either case. My error is :
Could Not create the Java Virtual Machine.
cmd:Command failed with exit code 8.

I can successfully deploy apps from Xamarin studio to either my phone or a virtual one, so SDK's should be all good.

What might be the problem? I have not yet found a solution. Please help me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I need a solution too